# GreenDao StringCondition?

Tags: greendao

I saw in the [documentation](http://greendao-orm.com/documentation/queries/) that there is a mystical class called `StringCondition` for executing custom SQL commands but the SDK doesn't recognize this?

is there a new version of this?

what am I missing?

Comment: I am using it happily with the latest greenDAO release. not sure if it still works in master but I cant see a reason why not. Can you add your example query and the error you get ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

import de.greenrobot.dao.WhereCondition.StringCondition;